# Is Java 8 Stream the solution I'm looking for?

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, apache-kafka

I'm building a tool to Consume data from Kafka and Insert them into MongoDB, with some manipulations between.

For now i'm doing :

```js
// Poll during X ms
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.of(100, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
// For each record, insert it into Mongo
for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
  System.out.println("Message of length ["+ record.value().length() +"] received.");
  Tools._insertReport(record.value());
}
```

I'm looking for a solution like a dynamic collection, in which I can pile up records, and the insert method will insert then remove records from the pile as it goes ? Like a internal message queuing..

Is Java 8 Streams something like that ? If not is there an obvious solution ?

Edit 1 :

Both solutions seems viable. Kafka Connector, and RxJava, since RxJava looks more like what I was looking for, I'll look into and post the result of my research here. Thank you all.

Comment: you are looking for rx-java maybe?

Comment: If you just want to transfer from Kafka into MongoDB, maybe try Connect and use a custom transformer. Or just KStream.

Comment: If you're wanting this to be a long-lived structure, then you probably want either RxJava for in-memory in a single JVM or a message queue like RabbitMQ (for communication between more than one program).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve but for reading message from Kafka and writing them into MongoDB, I'm suggesting that you use Kafka Connect with the mongoDB connector !
All the queuing is done by kafka connect natively without the need to write code.

You will find many mongodb connector that fits your case, here two of them :

https://github.com/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb/blob/master/README.md

https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/mongo.html

The latter may be a good choice to try first, it's more simple to use and lenses manages several other connectors.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Java 8 Streams something like that ?

Not really, no.

The obvious solution is literally create a fixed size `List<ConsumerRecord>`, then periodically check the size of that list... When full, loop over and flush to Mongo, as you would otherwise be doing one record at a time.

Perferably, though, you use Kafka Connect as it can manage exceptions, retries, and message conversions in a more reasonable way.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, Streams wasn't it at all, but RxJava is a suitable answer to my answer my use case. More precisely the Publish Subject is.

I created a class, were I initiated the said Publish Subject and I use the `.onNext()` function to pass my Kafka ConsumerRecord to the Subject. here is the definition :

```js
public static void _initRx(){
        RxRecordsList = PublishSubject.create();
        RxRecordsList.subscribe(_initRxRecordConsumer());
    }
    private static Observer<ConsumerRecord<String,String>> _initRxRecordConsumer(){
        return new Observer<ConsumerRecord<String,String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                System.out.println("Rx Subscrition : OK");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ConsumerRecord record) {
                System.out.println("Message received - Length : "+record.toString().length());
                MongoHelper._insertReport(record.value().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("Stream ended");
            }
        };
    }
```

And here is how I push data to it :

```js
while(true) {
  ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.of(100, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
  for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
    RxHDB_Records.RxRecordsList.onNext(record);
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's well done but it works so... that's a start. I have no clue of how to use the operators or how to change the date type from here. But still it's a start